# QSqlDatabase can't be removed - Queries still active

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

I started with c++ QT recently. 
I created class "ControllerOfDB" to hold pointer to my QSqlDatabase and few functions (to make inserts/selects). 
Example select function:

```
QList<data1> GetData1()
{
  QList<data1> output;

  if(!dataBase->isOpen())
      dataBase->open();
  if(dataBase->isOpen())
  {
    QSqlQuery* query = new QSqlQuery(*dataBase);
    query->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1");
    if(query->exec())
    while (query->next())
    {

        output.append( *(new data1(
                               query->value(0).toInt(), 
                               query->value(1).toString(), 
                               query->value(2).toInt(),
                               query->value(3).toInt(),
                               query->value(4).toInt(),
                               ))  );
    }
    query->clear();
    query->finish();
    delete query;
  }

  return output;
}
```

It was all working fine, until i had to add possibility to change db or login as different user. I modified Connect and Disconnect function. After few iterrations, this is what i get:

```
void Connect()
{
    dataBase = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", "Main"));

    dataBase->setHostName(hostName);
    dataBase->setPort(port);
    dataBase->setDatabaseName(dbName);
    dataBase->setUserName(userName);
    dataBase->setPassword(userPass);

    if(!dataBase->isOpen())
        dataBase->open();
}

 void Disconnect()
 {
    if(dataBase != NULL)
      if(dataBase->isOpen()){
        dataBase->close();
        dataBase->removeDatabase("Main");
        dataBase = NULL;
      }
 }
```

hostName, port, dbName, userName and userPass are also attributes of that class.

```
public:
  QSqlDatabase *dataBase;
  QString hostName;
  int port;
  QString dbName;
  QString userName;
  QString userPass;
```

whenever i try to diconnect and create new connection i recieve warnings/errors about queries of my current connections - even if i only "connected" ( = used function Connect() ).
I already saw few similar topics and documentation for it, saying i have to remove queries from scope, but at this point i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you look at `QSqlDatabase` document, the method `removeDatabase` is static, so your method `Disconnect` logic should be like:

```
void Disconnect()
{
    if(dataBase != NULL) {
        if(dataBase->isOpen()){
            dataBase->close();
        }
        delete dataBase;
        dataBase = NULL;
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("Main");
}
```